# Running subset of tests in Cucumber with maven

Tags: maven, cucumber, bdd

I have following problem, i have class (ExoertTest.java) with one feature (with @expert tag):

```
package opi;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/features/Expert.feature",
    tags = "@expert"
)
public class ExpertTest {
}
```

I want run only this one feature from maven with command

> mvn clean test -Ptest -Dcucumber.options="--tags @expert"

but no tests are executed, logs from console:

> [INFO] Running opi.ExpertTest None of the features at
>   [src/test/resources/features/Expert.feature] matched the filters:
>   [@expert]
>
> 0 Scenarios 0 Steps 0m0,000s
>
> [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed:
>   0.013 s - in opi.ExpertTest

Do You know why Cucumber dont see my @expert tag and this case is not executed?

I use Cucumber with Selenide

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i put tags in feature file instead of CucumberOptions in TestRunner.class and it works